# Binding a TextBlock's text to TabControl item in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, tags, tabcontrol, textblock

I have a WPF window with a tab control, and I'm defining the TabItems in the XAML file, like:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Name="tab1" Tag="Transactions"/>
    <TabItem Name="tab2" Tag="Promotions" />
    ...
</TabControl>
```

Elsewhere on the screen I have a textblock which I want to use to display the Tag value of the selected tab.  It works when the screen is initially loaded, and whenever the "transactions" tab is selected, but when a different tab is selected, it's blank.  Why is that, and how can I make it display the tag of any selected tab?  Here is the TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tabControl1, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected for me. (You did set the name of the TabControl, right?)

Note that if the TabControl is populated via ItemsSource unlike your example code the SelectedItem will not contain the TabItem but the data-object from which the TabItem is created, so the binding path `SelectedItem.Tag` does not work.

Code used:

```
<!-- Both controls enclosed in a Stackpanel -->
<TabControl Name="tabControl1">
    <TabItem Name="tab1" Tag="Transactions"/>
    <TabItem Name="tab2" Tag="Promotions" />
</TabControl>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tabControl1, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}"/>
```

The tab headers are obviously going to be empty but they are selectable.

Comment: No, there's no itemssource, it's populated exactly the way I described, with seven tabs hard-coded in the XAML file.  Can you show me the code you used, for your textblock and your tabcontrol?  My textblock is completely empty for all tabs except the first.

Comment: Wow that's pretty strange... I just pasted your textblock in and now it's working.  The only difference was that mine had a Name attribute.  I really have no idea what's different, but thanks.